# Sealed class as an entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to solve my inheritance problem with kotlin sealed class and forced problem with hibernate.

Here are my classes:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
sealed class LegalGuardian(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int? = null
)

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "MOTHER")
data class MotherLegalGuardian(
    @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
    val pesel: Pesel
) : LegalGuardian()

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "OTHER")
data class OtherLegalGuardian(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    @OneToOne
    val address: Address
) : LegalGuardian()
```

Here is poroblem that is thrown:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
>   at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)
>   at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
>   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:348)
>   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
>   at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
>   ... 95 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test object : X.MotherLegalGuardian
>   at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:43)
>   at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.getUnsavedIdentifierValue(UnsavedValueFactory.java:68)
>   at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierAttribute(PropertyFactory.java:61)
>   at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.(EntityMetamodel.java:141)
>   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.(AbstractEntityPersister.java:517)
>   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
>   ... 99 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:40)
>   ... 109 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: X.LegalGuardian.(Lkotlin/jvm/internal/DefaultConstructorMarker;)V
>   at X.MotherLegalGuardian.(LegalGuardian.kt)
>   ... 114 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how hibernate works. 
But I guess the issue is related to this notes from [sealed-classes docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html):

> A sealed class is abstract by itself, it cannot be instantiated
>   directly and can have abstract members.
>
> Sealed classes are not allowed to have non-private constructors (their
>   constructors are private by default).

Comment: So you would use abstract class with public constructor?

Comment: Sorry dude, as I said I have no idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is not in sealed class, but in the data class and constructors. When you are using primary constructors with arguments, there is no  default (no-arguments) constructor, which is required for hibernate. You can see the reason in the very end of the stacktrace:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: X.LegalGuardian.(Lkotlin/jvm/internal/DefaultConstructorMarker;)V at X.MotherLegalGuardian.(LegalGuardian.kt)

You can enable [no-arg](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#no-arg-compiler-plugin) and [jpa-support](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#jpa-support) plugins to get no-arg constructors generated.

Check out also [this article](https://kotlinexpertise.com/hibernate-with-kotlin-spring-boot/) which explains why data classes are not a good choice for hibernate.

Comment: I've removed dataclass but didn't helped. Same error

Comment: You'll need to enable plugins mentioned to get no-arg constructors generated even if you don't use data classes, because your classes does not have no-args constructors. Edited the answer to make it clearer.